# Unique time range or database schema for a scheduling system

Tags: schema

I'm having to design a table which contains scheduled times for media to be displayed. These scheduled times should not overlap.

In my SheduledSlot table I have:

```
id    integer PRIMARY KEY
begin datetime(or integer for SQLite)
end   datetime(or integer for SQLite unixtime)
media_item integer (foreign key)
```

How do I enforce a constraint which ensures a unique time range for each scheduled item?

Answer (score 3):

You should implement this on the database side in the method that can be called by your create schedule time and modify schedule time methods.

Answer (score 2):

You can implement such a functionality using triggers. It can be `INSTEAD INSERT/UPDATE` or `BEFORE INSERT/UPDATE` trigger depends on RDMS you are using. In the trigger body you raise an error if the new data does not pass validation.